# WatiN and IE comments

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, watin

Is there any way to get a page source along with IE comments via WatiN? WatiN exposes DocumentElement.outerHTML but it contains a document without the comments.

**EDIT** When we have a look at IE comments via View Source in IE, we see something like:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<p>Welcome to Internet Explorer.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

But when we have a look at the actually rendered HTML via the document object, we see only:

```
<p>Welcome to Internet Explorer.</p>
```

I.e. the IE comments are not included into the rendered document, but the usual HTML comments are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to top of your code:

```
using SHDocVw;
```

and use this to get the actual HTML content

```
InternetExplorer internetExplorer = (InternetExplorer)browser.InternetExplorer;
string htmlContent = internetExplorer.Document.documentElement.OuterHTML;
```

Good luck.

**Edit:**
It seems I misunderstood what you want. After you edit your post, I tried something. Opened a website in Opera and Chrome which include `<!--[if IE]-->`, then ran this command in the console: `document.head.innerHTML`. Both browsers gave output with the `[if IE]`, however when trying it in IE it seems after the page is rendered IE removes all of these.

There must be some way to achieve this but I couldn't find a solution without downloading the whole page with `System.Net` or something else then reading its content.

**Edit 2:**
I found another way, but not sure if you like the solution. Look at this code: http://pastebin.com/4EvLSuEL

It makes an ajax call to load the page content, then pastes the result into a hidden `textarea`. After that, by using WatiN's `ElementWithTag` we get that `textarea` value into our string `myContent`.

Hope it helps you, this is what I can do best.

Comment: As I said above, the outerHTML property contains actually rendered HTML which doesn't include IE comments (usual HTML comments are rendered ok and are present in DOM tree as nodes with the type COMMENT_NODE). I'll update the post to be more clear.

Comment: From what I investigated the only thing to achieve this is to download the whole page again in my case. To do this via JavaScript with browser.RunScript is a good idea.

Comment: Or, even the better solution is just to download the document like this `new WebClient().DownloadString(url)`